# Why is it called linear logic?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic, linear-logic

Why is it called ["Linear" Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic)? What's linear about it?

Comment: Maybe useful: Jean-Yves Girard & Paul Taylor, [PROOFS AND TYPES](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf), Cambridge UP (1989), **Ch.12.3 Linearity**, page 98.

Comment: See also Jean-Yves Girard, [*Linear logic* (1987)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=35357), page 16, for the def of *linear* function (associated to *coherent spaces*) and the definitions (page 19) of *linear negation* and *linear implication*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Girard himself, in his native language (cf. Girard, [Cours de Logique I](http://recherche.ircam.fr/equipes/repmus/mamux/hermann.pdf), Hermann, 2006, Section 1.B.2), writes:

"La logique linéaire est issue d'une prise en compte systématique de l'interprétation catégorique. En particulier, les *espaces cohérents* [...], proches des espaces vectoriels [...] font apparaître des structures logiques familières en algèbre linéaires [...]"

Translation: 
"Linear logic developed from systematically taking into consideration the categorical interpretation. In particular, *coherent spaces* [...], similar to vector spaces [...] give rise to logical structures which are familiar from linear algebra."

So, in one sentence, it is called *linear* logic because it involves semantics which *resemble* structures from *linear* algebra.

Comment: May someone with a French keyboard care to add in all the diacritical signs?

Comment: I see. So for instance because times distributes over plus? I'm curious, what's the analogue of "with" and "par" in linear algebra?

Comment: Well, an analogy does not necessarily imply that there is _the_ correct answer to your question. You _can_ see the similarity you named as one.

Comment: @psquid: “with” is the Cartesian product. The “times” is tensor product of vector spaces.